# xlrd: Why is end_colx 1-indexed when start_colx is 0-indexed?

Tags: python, xlrd

Given an Excel sheet with the following layout:

```
  A                    | B
1 Name of First Column | Name of Second Column
2 Value in First Column| Value in Second Column
```

[`xlrd`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html) sure has an odd way of indexing into it. First, some setup ...

```
import xlrd
f = open("example.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=f.read())
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Let's see what's in the first row using [`row_values`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet.row_values-method)

```
print sh.row_values(0, start_colx=0, end_colx=1)
```

Result?

```
[u'Name of First Column']
```

What went wrong? The first, unlabeled, parameter of `row_values` is `rowx`. ["'rowx' is a row index, counting from zero"](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet-class) And the two `colx`? ["'colx' is a column index, counting from zero."](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet-class)

Both `colx` should be counting from zero, you might think. And if I specify in `end_colx` I'd like to end on column `1`, I mean the second column, counting from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlrd`'s observed behavior reminds me of python's slicing notation, which is like this:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | H | e | l | p | A |
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5
-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

(given a string of "HelpA" -- [that's from the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings))

So, if you start on `0` and end on `0` (`[0:0]`) you won't retrieve anything.

If anyone has a better answer, I'd love to hear it. Just wanted to document this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right answer. The docs you link to for `row_values` say `Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given row`, so it makes sense that the boundaries work like they do for Python slices. The "end" index is really "just past the end". If you want to slice to the end of the row, pass `None` as `end_colx` (or just skip the argument, as `None` is the default).